# Implicitly casting PetscReal to the real part of PetscComplex

Tags: petsc, c, complex-arithmetic

The version of PETSc installed on my machine has `PetscScalar` set to be complex. I am making a matrix which has all real entries.

Something like the following code compiles:

```
PetscScalar value_for_matrix;
value_for_matrix=some_expression*returns_PetscReal;
```

Is the real value returned by the right hand side put into the real part of the PetscScalar value? If this doesn't work, how should I put a PetscReal value into the real part of a complex PetscScalar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this does exactly what you would expect. If you want to create a complex number explicitly, you can multiply real values by `PETSC_i`. Note that you can use `PetscRealPart()`, `PetscImaginaryPart()`, `PetscAbsScalar()`, and `PetscConj()` to manipulate complex numbers.